# Redmine does not return the web page

Tags: redmine

I migrated a Redmine installation from an Ubuntu machine to a Debian one (both 32-bits), and now for some reason, for some users it doesn't return the page but only a 200 OK message. Here is the flow (from Wireshark):

```
GET /issues/142 HTTP/1.1
Host: debian:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _redmine_session=BAh7DCIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMStIM1RBNTlNelZVUXlUazgrR1pUNGUvNGdEbytUZzRyMVFSUnBvNGhlSDg9Ihd0aW1lbG9nX2luZGV4X3NvcnQiEnNwZW50X29uOmRlc2MiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQiJThiMDk0MzVhOTEzYTI0MzVjOGEzYTRmNDU0NzcwMTAwIgx1c2VyX2lkaQoiFmlzc3Vlc19pbmRleF9zb3J0IgxpZDpkZXNjIg1wZXJfcGFnZWlpIgpxdWVyeXsHOg9wcm9qZWN0X2lkaQc6B2lkaQo%3D--8588c221c0642a12f396239455fb702aec14c9c9; my_wiki_session=f70ae11e1c533c86f0e039d63cf3f69c; my_wikiUserID=1; my_wikiUserName=Yasin
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 16:30:16 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2010-08-16)
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see, I get nothing from the server. This is mostly random because this blank page happens sometimes for some users, and for other users it almost never returns the page...

This only happens for issues, any other page I've tested works fine (like listing the issues, creating a new one, etc...).

- RedMine version 2.0.3 with WEBrick

**EDIT**: Looks like when people use the IP of the RedMine server (192.168.1.5) it works fine. But when using the host name, it doesn't show the issues (only the issues).

**EDIT2**: Now it shows all pages in blank...

This looks like random... I'm really lost here. Any idea about what can be the cause? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Redmine version? What web server (passenger)? Installed all dependencies (gems)? File system permissions checked? What does it say when running in the built-in webrick?

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed [latest RedMine version](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1850) (2.1.4) and followed all steps in the [installation process](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) (except initializing data to not overwrite my existing DB) and now it works fine.

I probably only forgot to run

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```